# Creating a ObservableCollection<T> class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, observablecollection

I have a `person` class and would like to create and `ObservableCollection<person>` class called `people`.  I have seen some examples of similar implementations, but don't fully understand the differences in them.  For instance:

```
public class people : ObservableCollection<person>
{
    public people()
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class people
{
    ObservableCollection<person> public people()
    {
    }
}
```

Is one of these implementations fundamentally wrong?  I do not have any working code, but would like a nudge in the right direction to start.

**EDIT (per @Groky's suggestion):**

I am looking to create a `ObservableCollection<Person>`.    I would like to use this collection in a MVVM setting with binding. Specifically, I would like to bind all Persons first and last name, for instance, to a custom control.

FIRST: Is it bad practice to create a class as such, or should I implement the ObservableCollection within the viewmodel as @Groky suggests?

SECOND: Is using an ObservableCollection even the correct route to solve this type of problem?

Comment: The latter one doesn't even compile.
What exactly you are trying to do there? The first one is ok, but you need to add other constructors, which you can pass an existing enumerable or list of Persons to.

Comment: Yes, the second one is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: That's good to know!  I am trying to create a ``people`` class in which I can access one property of each ``person`` in ``people``.  Then that data will be bound to a control in WPF.  Am I on the right track with an ``ObservableCollection<person>``?

Comment: Why do you want to create a People class? Creating custom collections simply to group things is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I would like to load multiple ``person`` data and be able to return a property for all People, normally the distinct() of that property.  I hope that makes sense.  Can you expand on why it's a bad idea?  What would be a preferred method?  This is very new to me and I'm trying to pick my way through it one step at a time.

Comment: May be he wants to do more in people class,some private jobs and functionality for people

Comment: @StinkerPeter: I think you should update your answer to reflect your recent comments to people. Your question is misleading as-is and you're unlikely to get useful answers. In particular, mention what you're trying to do with WPF binding! That's quite important!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern with WPF and that you're trying to create a ViewModel class.

As a previous answerer mentioned, your two options describe 1) Inheritence 2) Delegation. Which one to choose depends on the *meaning* of what you're trying to represent.

You would choose inheritence if you're logically trying to add something to the collection of People. However, because you hint you're wanting to bind the additional properties in WPF, that suggests to me that you're not logically adding a property to the collection; more you're adding a property *alongside* the collection. So in this case you're creating a ViewModel in WPF parlance.

Here's an example:

```
public PeopleViewModel
{
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Items { get; private set; }

    public int NumberOfPeople 
    { 
        get { return Items.Distinct().Count; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several choices, for example inheritance or delegation pattern. So in the 1st variant you have inheritance pattern, in the 2nd composition, mixin and aspect pattern.

Comment: One of my biggest hurdles is finding the proper terminology to search for answers with.  I am vaguely aware of inheritance, but have not read much about delegation.  Thanks for the pointers.  I will use those terms to help the direction forward.